# Assert.AreEqual fails while it shouldn't

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mstest, assert

I have a really weird behavior which I cannot explain.

I have the following class:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a method which returns a `Project` object:

```
public Project GetByName(string Name)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        Project project = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Project))
                                 .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", Name))
                                 .UniqueResult<Project>();

        return project;
    }
}
```

I have added a Unit Test to test the `GetByName` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetByName()
{
    IProjectsRepository projectRepository = new ProjectsRepository();

    var expected = new Project { Id = 1000, Name = "Project1" };
    var actual = projectRepository.GetByName(expected.Name);

    Assert.AreEqual<Project>(expected, actual);
}
```

But when I run the unit test it fails when comparing the type of the two objects with the following error:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<MyProject.NHibernate.Project>.
>   Actual:<MyProject.NHibernate.Project>.

Why is the assertion failing?

---

Isn't [Assert.AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx) asserting only on the properties of the objects?

According to the documentation:

> **Assert.AreEqual Method (Object, Object)**
>
> Verifies that two specified objects are equal. The assertion fails if
>   the objects are not equal.
>
> **Assert.AreSame Method**
>
> Verifies that specified object variables refer to the same object.

Comment: *Verifies that two specified objects are equal*. Without overriding the Equals method your objects will not be.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to override the equals method to test for equality. By default it will use reference comparison, and since your expected and actual objects are in different locations in memory it will fail. Here is what you should try:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if (obj is Project)
        {
            var that = obj as Project;
            return this.Id == that.Id && this.Name == that.Name;
        }

        return false; 
    }
}
```

You can also check out the [guidelines for overriding equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: at last full answer with **reasons** why the test is failling

Comment: @Corey hmm, sorry we pretty much said the same. Thought the answers only supplied text w/o an example. +1 though

Comment: Ok, I got it. I thought that just using `AreEqual ` will give me what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that your `Project` class overrides the equals method. Currently you are comparing object references, and since you have 2 different objects of `Project` your `Assert.AreEqual()` will fail.

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        var result = false;
        var project = o as Project;
        if (project != null)
        {
            result = Id == project.Id;
            result &= Name.Equals(project.Name);
            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

With the equals method in place, you can use the `Assert.AreEqual`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetByName()
{
    IProjectsRepository projectRepository = new ProjectsRepository();

    var expected = new Project { Id = 1000, Name = "Project1" };
    var actual = projectRepository.GetByName(expected.Name);

    Assert.AreEqual<Project>(expected, actual);
}
```

PS: If you are overriding Equals it's [advised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to also override the Hashcode.

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashcode = Id.GetHashCode();
        hashCode ^= Name.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
```

### AreSame vs AreEqual

`Assert.AreSame` will still fail, even when you override the `Equals` method. That method actually checks if the references are pointing to the same instance. Which in your case, they will not.

`Assert.AreEqual` will simply check if the objects are equal, which will be done by calling `expected.Equals(actual)`. That will result in true once you implemented the `override bool Equals()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two different objects that hold the same data. You should overload Equals method in your Project class, and implement comparison by id there.

Answer (score 1):

An easy alternative would be this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(string1 == string2, "Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple class and you want to compare it easily you can use tuples:

```
using System.Linq

public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestProject()
{
    var collection1 = Project[] { new() { Id = 1, Name = "Project1" } };
    var collection2 = Project[] { new() { Id = 2, Name = "Project2" } };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
       collection1.Select(p => (p.Id, p.Name)).ToArray(),
       collection2.Select(p => (p.Id, p.Name)).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but I thought I'd add a really simple implementation that works for any class:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
     return GetType().GetProperties().All(property => property.GetValue(this) == property.GetValue(obj));
}
```

It basically loops through each property and checks the values against each other.

Comment: Except when your class contains stuff like lists or objects that are considered equal by business logic but don't have an overridden .Equals(). Also, overriding Equals() like this can have funky side-effects when you use instances of this class in lists. Basically: don't alter your code for testing.