# Assert.AreEqual failed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I wrote service layer code as follows:

```
public GetAllCategoriesResponse GetAllCategories()
{
     GetAllCategoriesResponse response = new GetAllCategoriesResponse();
     IEnumerable<Category> categories = _categoryRepository.GetAll();
     response.Categories = categories.ConvertToCategoryViews();

     return response;
}
```

Then I wrote my Test class as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class ProductCatalogServiceTest
{
   Mock<ICategoryRepository> _categoryRepository;
   ProductCatalogService _catalogService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _categoryRepository = new Mock<ICategoryRepository>();
        _catagoryService = new ProductCatagoryService( _categoryRepository.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_All_Catagories()
    {
        AutoMapperBootStrapper.ConfigureAutoMapper();
        var catagories = new List<Category>();
        catagories.Add(new Category() {Id=1, Name = "Half Shirt" });
        catagories.Add(new Category() {Id=2, Name = "Full Shirt" });
        catagories.Add(new Category() {Id=4, Name = "Pant" });

        _categoryRepository.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(catagories.AsEnumerable());

        var result = _catagoryService.GetAllCategories();

        var response = new GetAllCategoriesResponse();
        response.Categories = catagories.ConvertToCategoryViews();

        Assert.AreEqual(response, result);
    }
}
```

The mapping between Category and CategoryView as follows:

```
public class AutoMapperBootStrapper
{

    public static void ConfigureAutoMapper()
    {
        // Category
        Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryView>();
     }
}
```

When I run my test is shows me following message:
**Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: Shoppingcart.Services.Messages.GetAllCategoriesResponse>. Actual:Shoppingcart.Services.Messages.GetAllCategoriesResponse>.**

Comment: This post should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15463105/961919

Comment: @e.beyer is probably right. `EqualityComparer<GetAllCategoriesResponse>.Default.Equals(response, result)` returns `false` when `response` and `result` are distinct instances. It does not matter if the two instances look the same there. If you want to change that, override `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`.